# Use of "yield" in proofs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I have started to learn discrete maths on my own, and while writing my first proofs, I am sometimes drawn to use the verb "yield" (e.g. Let $a=2b²+5b+4$ for some integer b. Since $\Bbb Z$ is closed under addition and multiplication, a will yield an integer).

Is it OK, plain wrong, bad form? Thanks!

Comment: In this case, I'd simply say that it *is* an integer ... But this question should best be answered by native speakers of English

Answer (score 2):

I would say in your particular case, it's odd to use *yield* since you can simply say $a$ will **be** an integer. I would say

> since $\mathbb Z$ is closed under addition and multiplication, $a$ is also an integer.

I would reserve the verb yield to functions, so for example, if you have $f(x)=x^2$, you could say

> Since $\mathbb Z$ is closed under multiplication, the function $f$ yields an integer with integer input.

and even that is slightly weird. I honestly can't think of any use of *yield* that can't be improved and simplified by using the verb *be*.

---

Thanks to Erick Wong, I can now provide an example of a good use of the verb *yield* where you cannot replace it with *be*. It's when you would want to say "results in", like when you are simplifying or differentiating or doing some other thing to an equation. For example, you can say

> Simplifying the equation $a^2 + b^2 + 2c^2 = r^2 + c^2$ yields $a^2+b^2+c^2=r^2$

Comment: You would use "yields" as a synonym of "results in", describing the outcome of a process.  Example "Differentiating both sides of this equation yields..."

Comment: @ErickWong You're right!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the first answer, I think 'yields' is over the top here and it is always good to write mathematics in the simplest possible way.

'Yields' is much more appropriate for when we are applying some sort of process or operation to something in order to change it into another form, an example would be 'applying the fourier transform yields the frequency domain form of our function'.